# How to predict prices in house price competition in kaggle using R?

Tags: r, prediction, kaggle

I take part in kaggle competition: [House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data).
As a baseline I want to create linear regression.
At first, I clean my data.
Secondly, I select only numeric variables.

```
data_num<-data[sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))]
train<-data_num[1:1460,]
test<-data_num[1461:nrow(data_num),]
```

Then I plot histogram to see distribution of SalePrice. As we see, here there is a skewness.
[image]
Because of this, I create log(SalePrice). It's better.
[image]

My linear model:
model<-lm(SalePrice~.,train)
summary(model)

```
model2<-lm(SalePrice~LotArea+OverallQual+OverallCond+YearBuilt+
             MasVnrArea+ExterQual+BsmtQual+BsmtCond+BsmtFinSF1+`1stFlrSF`+  
             `2ndFlrSF`+BsmtFullBath+BedroomAbvGr+KitchenAbvGr+KitchenQual+
             TotRmsAbvGrd+GarageCars+GarageCond+WoodDeckSF+ScreenPorch,train)
p<-predict(model2, test)

c<-cbind(price, p)


RMSE=sqrt(mean((log(p)-log(price$SalePrice))^2))
```

> #RMSE 0.4215566

1. Do I have the right tactic?
2. What do I predict using log?
3. If I plot geom_point log(actual) and log(predicted) it looks like this
   [image]
   why are the dots so scattered?

If I use random forest to find out important variables I get this:
[image]

For me is importanr to build a linear model. I want to compare it with more complex models xgboost, lasso and other

Comment: do you need so many predictor variables? it would be interesting to see by how much each variable is able to predict the variation in prices.

Comment: @D.J I added a picture